# Programmatically add application icon to dock on install

Tags: macos, package, dmg

I would like my application to be automatically added to the dock after the package (DMG) is installed?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

There's a couple ways to do this, Andrew, and a lot of this depends on how you're doing your application installing.

If you are using PackageMaker to install your app, you can run a "postflight" script which adds your app's icon to the "defaults" (i.e. the preferences) of the dock. [This older MacRumors thread shows how to do that](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=344100).

If you are not using PackageMaker, then you might have to run an Applescript from within your app that does the same "defaults" writing trick. [Here's a thread on AskDifferent that shows how](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64307/alternative-to-additemtodock-from-henri-shustak).

In both cases you need to kill the dock (or Finder?) and restart it in order to get the change to pick up and show.

Comment: Michael, I don't want to run an applescript within my app. I want to add my app into the dock bar as soon as copying it to Application folder. Is that possible?

Comment: See why I commented "this depends on how you're doing your application installing"?  If this is a drag & drop install, there's no "trigger" you can launch automatically from the DMG to make this happen.  You *must* do the dock icon Applescript thing from within your app, or you need to use an installer and then the postflight script trick.

Answer (score 1):

I  would suggest you run the following AppleScript code, replacing `myapp` with the app you want to add to de dock, including its path.

In the example below, I am adding the system app "System Preferences", but you can do the same with your own path, just assign the path of your app to the `myapp` variable.

```
 on run
   set myapp to "/Applications/System Preferences.app"
   try
     tell application "Dock" to quit
   end try
   do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>" & myapp & "</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'"
   try
     tell application "Dock" to activate
   end try
 end run
```

This follows the suggestion given by Michael, but it should be more gentle as it just *quits* the Dock rather thank killing it.

If you prefer bash, you could run the following code, again assigning the path of your own app to the `myapp` variable.

**Note**: in the bash case, you have to use double slashes when specifying your the path, as you can see in the example.

```
#!/bin/bash
myapp="//Applications//System Preferences.app"
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>$myapp</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>"
osascript -e 'tell application "Dock" to quit'
osascript -e 'tell application "Dock" to activate'
```